# Difference between APIView class and viewsets class?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

What are the differences between the **APIView** and **ViewSets** classes? I am following [Django REST-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) official documentation. I find it lacking in examples.

Can you explain the above difference with a suitable example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [generics vs viewset in django rest framework, how to prefer which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482453/generics-vs-viewset-in-django-rest-framework-how-to-prefer-which-one-to-use)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`APIView` is the most basic class that you usually override when defining your REST view. You usually define your methods like get, put, delete and others  see:  http://www.cdrf.co/3.5/rest_framework.views/APIView.html. With `APIView` you define your **view** and add it to your urls like so:

```
# in views.py
class MyAPIView(APIView):
     ... #here you put your logic check methods you can use

# in urls.py
url(r'^posts$', MyAPIView.as_view()), #List of all the posts
```

Because certain things like getting `/post/4`, deleting `/post/4`, getting all posts, updating posts, and creating new posts are so common DRF provides `ViewSet`s.

Before you use `ViewSet`s, let me tell you about Generic Classes. They things very well, but you need to provide the full API end point like I did with my `MyAPIView` view (again for more info check http://www.cdrf.co/ or http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). So you would have to define your own urls path.

But with `ViewSet`s you create **ViewSet** that actually merges all the above described operations and also you don't need to define the url path you, instead you use a router that makes paths for you like this:

```
 # views.py
 class PostViewSet(ViewSet):  # here you subclass ViewSet check methods you can override, you have also ModelViewSet,...


 # urls.py 
 router = routers.DefaultRouter()
 router.register(r'post', PostViewSet, base_name='Post')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49489829/454023 

Summarises it beautifully.

Comment: Here's one nice answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879333/8454203

Answer (score 25):

**APIView** allow us to define functions that match standard HTTP methods like GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, etc.

**Viewsets** allow us to define functions that match to common API object actions like : LIST, CREATE, RETRIEVE, UPDATE, etc.

**Viewsets** are also used to write logic to perform standard database operations and to interface with a database back-end. And are usually used for existing database model to manage predefined objects.

Answer (score 15):

The functions you add to the APIView are different than the functions you add to the ViewSet class.

- **APIView**: you add functions for the particular HTTP method you want to support on your endpoint. Ex: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
- **ViewSet**: you would add functions that represent actions that you'd perform on a typical API. Ex: LIST, CREATE, RETRIEVE, UPDATE

Answer (score 6):

Viewsets and APIView both allow us to write logic for end point but Viewsets dont define functions which map to HTTP methods instead map to common API object actions