# What is the difference in use or inherit from APIView and Model ViewSet

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I would meet the difference with respect to when use APIView and when use ModelViewSet when I want serialize my models with respect to get a list of their objects/records?

For example, in the [APIView documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) we have that with the ListUser class and their get method we can get the list of users

```
class ListUsers(APIView):
    """
    View to list all users in the system.

    * Requires token authentication.
    * Only admin users are able to access this view.
    """
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a list of all users.
        """
        usernames = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)
```

I have been get this same list of users using ModelViewSet of this way:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ('username', 'is_player', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'team' , 'email', )
```

How to can I identify when should I use APIView or ModelViewSet for this task?

Comment: Except for the comparision using example classes, here're the possible duplicates of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379654/difference-between-apiview-class-and-viewsets-class

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482453/generics-vs-viewset-in-django-rest-framework-how-to-prefer-which-one-to-use/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Question is too open though I'll try to answer it.

First thing first, `APIView` or `ViewSet` aren't tied to models while `ModelViewSet`, `GenericAPIView`, `ListAPIView` (and co) are.

The major difference between *View and *ViewSet is that *ViewSet are meant to work with routers and provide a single class to expose a Resource while *View will require two (one for list/create, another for detail/update/delete).

Note that `APIView` is the most lower level and will only tie to HTTP verbs (get/post/put...) while `ViewSet` or `GenericAPIView` will have CRUD such as list / update...

In order to expose a Django's Model, you'll need either

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

or

```
class UserListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserRetrieveUpdateDestroyView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's very illustrative. With `ListCreateAPIView` can I update (PUT) some model which have ManyToManyFields?

Comment: The view for updates should be UpdateAPIView (or UserRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView). I just updated my post. Note that the related fields are the domain of the serializer, not the view.

Comment: I understood @Linovia, I was thinking in inheritance of `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49489829/8454203 has beautifully explained the same.